# How to Send Headers Through PHP Proxy?

Tags: php, ajax, proxy, header, cross-domain

Okay, so I have an issue with an AJAX request. I currently have this URL:

http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&safe=off&gbv=2&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=cars+imagesize%3A500x500&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&start=0

I then pass it to my proxy script by modifying the string to this:

proxy.php?url=http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&safe=off&gbv=2&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=cars+imagesize%3A500x500&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&start=0

I need to use the PHP proxy script to grab that page's HTML so that I can then parse through it with javascript. However, the problem is that the headers in that URL are also being sent to the proxy script, and as a result, I get a 'malformed or illegal request' error. I'm pretty sure the two different sets of headers are the problem, because if I just replace the original URL string with 'http://wwww.google.com', the proxy returns the HTML of the page correctly.

So basically, I don't know how to fix this. I'm a complete PHP noob, and I tried escaping the original URL before I appended it to the 'proxy.php?url=', but that doesn't fix  anything. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out- you need to use encodeURIComponent() on the original URL string before you append it to the proxy string.